# Install managed package in Marketing Cloud automatically using Install URL WITHOUT publishing on AppExchange

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Note that this post is specific to Marketing Cloud. I know that you can have unmanaged packages in Salesforce and install them by clicking a link without ever listing them on AppExchange.

What I'm trying to figure out is, can you do this with Marketing Cloud? We have created a Marketing Cloud app via the manual process, IE, Create Installed package, component, set endpoints, etc.

What I want to know is, can we create a link to install that same package and configuration in other Marketing Cloud instances? Based on this link, you *can* if you list it on AppExchange, but we aren't ready for that yet.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/list-app-appexchange.htm

At this link, item 5 says you'll receive an install link *after* you finish security review. This only applies if you are listing the application on AppExchange though, which we don't want to do yet. Does anyone know if I can get this Install URL, *without* putting my app on AppExchange?

If that didn't make any sense, what I'm really after is the ability to click and install a Marketing Cloud package, like Deployment manager or Query Studio for example. I can do this all manually, but I want to be able to click a link.

Comment: AppExchange listings can be private, so you can have the listing, go through security review, pass review and have the package all ready but no one can find it on the AppExchange.

Comment: oooo that's interesting @PhilW, I was not aware of that. If that is the case, that should work

Comment: @PhilW any idea how I get someone at Salesforce to guide me through this? Step 1 mentions joining partner community and that someone would reach out to me, but no one eve did.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't deal with this. Perhaps someone else here can help you with the first steps? Alternatively you could post on the partner Q&A forum perhaps?

Comment: great idea @PhilW I can try that